# multi-dimensional container of any size and converts it into a one dimensional associative array

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion, hash

Write a function that accepts a multi-dimensional container of any size and converts it into a one dimensional associative array whose keys are strings representing their value's path in the original container.

So `{ 'one' => {'two' => 3, 'four' => [ 5,6,7]}, 'eight'=> {'nine'=> {'ten'=>11}}}`

would become
:
`"{'one/two' => 3,'one/four/0' => 5, 'one/four/1' => 6, 'one/four/2' => 7, 'eight/nine/ten' : 11}"`

I've gotten this so far... But am having a lot of issues. Any pointers to things I am overlooking?

```
def oneDimHash(hash)
  if hash.is_a?(Fixnum)
    puts "AHHH"
  else
    hash.each_pair do |key,value|
      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        @temp_key << key << '/'
        oneDimHash(value)
      elsif value.is_a?(Array)
        value.each_with_index do |val,index|
          puts index
          @temp_key << "#{index}"
          oneDimHash(val)
        end
      else
        @temp_key << key
        @result["#{@temp_key}"] = "#{value}"
        @temp_key = ''
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Care to describe some of the issue you're trying to overcome?

Answer (score 0):

It's immediately suspect to me that you are using instance variables instead of method arguments / local variables.  Very likely that is producing messed-up keys, at least.  Supposing that the method signature cannot be modified, you can work around the need for additional arguments by delegating to a helper function.  Perhaps I'd try an approach along these lines:

```
def oneDimHash(o)
  oneDimHashInternal("", o, {})
end

def oneDimHashInternal(keyStem, o, hash)
  if o.is_a? Hash
    o.each_pair do |key, value|
      oneDimHashInternal("#{keystem}/#{key}", value, hash)
    end
  elsif o.is_a? Array
    # Work this out for yourself
  else
    # Store the (non-container) object in hash
    # Work this out for yourself
  end

  hash
end
```

Note also that there are `Enumerable`s that are neither Arrays nor Hashes.  I don't know whether you need to account for such.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def oneDimHash(obj,parent="")
  unless obj.is_a?(Hash)
    puts "AHHH"  # or may be better: raise "AHHH"
  else
    obj.flat_map do |key,value|
      combined_key = [parent,key.to_s].join '/' 
      case value
        when Hash then oneDimHash(value,combined_key).to_a
        when Array then value.each_with_index.map { |v,i| [combined_key+"/#{i}",v] }
        else [ [combined_key,value] ]
      end
    end.to_h
  end
end
```